# Calculate with two SQL results

Tags: sql, divide

Is it possible to divide two result from two different SQL statements?

Example:

Table1

```
Entry1
Entry2
Entry3
...
```

Table2

```
Entry1
Entry2
Entry3
...
```

Calculation (Division):

```
Table1.Entry1/Table2.Entry1
Table1.Entry2/Table2.Entry2
Table1.Entry3/Table2.Entry3
…
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Sure. If you have columns that connect these records. How are the tables connected to each other?

Answer (score 0):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  In order to do what you want, you need a "key" of some sort of joining the tables.  Let me assume that you have a column that specifies the ordering.  Then you can create the key using `row_number()`:

```
select t1.entry1 / t2.entry2
from (select t1.*, row_number() over (order by ?) as seqnum
      from table1 t1
     ) t1 join
     (select t2.*, row_number() over (order by ?) as seqnum
      from table1 t2
     ) t2
     on t1.seqnum = t2.seqnum;
```

The `?` is for the respective column in each table that specifies the ordering of the rows.

Comment: doesn't the above suggests that both tables have the same number of records and no gaps between the made-up keys etc? wouldn't it be better to actually join the tables on a common key (PK to FK) or on some other natural key?

Comment: @BertrandLeroy . . . The OP implies that there is no such key and the `join` is based on the (perceived) position in the table.